# How to search for code containing lambda expressions in INTELLIJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda

How to search for code containing lambda expressions in INTELLIJ?

Intellij is able to detect lambda expressions. Does it provide a search option to retrieve all lambda expressions in a java project?

Comment: While there are syntactical constructs that need IDE support to be searched without ambiguity, plain text searching for `->` should be sufficient for finding all lambda expressions…

Answer (score 1):

You can use Structural Search to search for lambda expressions. Use the Existing Template called *lambdas*.